# ASP.NET 2.0 System.AccessViolationException in Event Viewer

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, memory, powerbuilder

An application compiled under .NET 2.0 running under IIS in its own app pool is crashing and causing the app pool to stop. The Event Viewer is giving the below details:

```
Application ID: /xx/xxxx/1/ROOT/my_application_name_here
Process ID: 6600

Exception: System.AccessViolationException

Message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

StackTrace:    at b(oa* , PBTransaction , Boolean )
   at c(oa* , PBTransaction )
   at Sybase.PowerBuilder.DB.PBSQL.Stop(IntPtr dbthis, PBTransaction transaction)
   at Sybase.PowerBuilder.PBSessionBase.StopTransaction(PBTransaction trans)
   at Sybase.PowerBuilder.PBTransaction.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Sybase.PowerBuilder.PBPowerObject.Finalize()
```

The application in question is an ASMX web service built in Power Builder.
The stack trace doesnt go any further. If i capture the same error in Debug Diagnostic Analyser, it gives the following additional memory details:

[image]

What could be the underlying error here? Are there any ways to find more information about this issue?

Edit: I have since disabled Rapid Fail Protection and the app pool doesnt stop upon crash. But still want to get to the bottom of the error

Comment: Such issues are caused by native memory corruption, so dump analysis is usually the only way to learn more. If you are not familiar with the necessary skills, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com The call stack seems to be PowerBuilder specific, but for native issues the actual culprit can be something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the application pool managed pipeline mode Integrated to Classic and make sure it is using the .net version 2.0.

[image]

Comment: The OP should also check the Enable 32-Bit Applications setting for the App Pool and ensure that it is set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Debug Diagnostic tool to set a hang rule, or capture the dump file.
[Download this tool (Debug Diagnostics Tool)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en)
Instructions:
[Debug Diagnostics tool to troubleshoot a process that has stopped responding in IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919792)
[Debug Diagnostics tool to troubleshoot an IIS process that stops unexpectedly](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919789)

Setup all PDB files path and analyze dump:
[How to Use Debug Diagnostics to Analyze a Memory Dump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-use-debug-diagnostics-to-analyze-a-memory-dump)

Answer (score 0):

This error should not happen in the managed code. This might solve the issue:

Go to Visual Studio Debugger to bypass this exception:

```
Tools menu ->Options -> Debugging -> General -> Uncheck this option "Suppress JIT optimization on module load"
```